# sql query to convert existing column entries into row headers

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pivot

the above question is very unclear let me show you what I mean..

I have a table of the following form

```
name ---- measure ----- value
xxx-----------m1--------------x1
xxx-----------m2--------------x2
xxx-----------m3--------------x3
yyy-----------m1--------------y1
yyy-----------m2--------------y2
yyy-----------m3--------------y3
```

---

I want to convert the above table to below form

```
name --- m1 --- m2 --- m3
xxx------x1-----x2-----x3
yyy------y1-----y2-----y3
```

Comment: Do you want to change column format or data format?

Comment: If you don't know the measures going into the target table, you will need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: in the second table m1, m2, m3 are the column headers.

Comment: Are m1, m2, m3 fix or dynamic?

Comment: every name has all the measures and their respective values.

Comment: I'm hoping there has to be some way to do this using sql, or else I can do it using python.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk I want to change both column and data format

Comment: `crosstab` function from the `tablefunc` module. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to pivot your table

```
select name,
  MAX(case when measure = 'm1' then value end) m1,
  MAX(case when measure = 'm2' then value end) m2,
  MAX(case when measure = 'm3' then value end) m3
from tableName
group by name
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5b5ff/1)

To handle pivoting when column values are not fixed , you should try doing this using [crosstab](http://rowsandcolumns.blogspot.in/2011/10/postgresql-crosstab-query-rotate-table.html) function

Answer (score 0):

If the columns `m1`, `m2` and `m3` are fixed then this is the way:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET m1 = t.value
FROM tbl t
WHERE tbl.name = t.name AND measure = 'm1';
```

And similarly for `m2` and `m3`.
Only that this will create duplicates. To remove which, you should do this:

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE measure = 'm2' OR measure = 'm3';
```

Comment: There is no column `m1` (or `m2`, `m3`)

Comment: The second "table" is the output syllogismos wants from the query.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
select m11.name,m1,m2,m3 from(select name,value as m1 from tab where measure='m1')as m11,
(select name,value as m2 from tab where measure='m2' )as m12,
(select name,value as m3 from tab where measure='m3')as m13 where m11.name=m12.name and m11.name=m13.name and m12.name=m13.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this with simple script as you want this one time procedure.

1. Insert into new table m1 value with name

   INSERT into new_table(name, m1) 
   select name, value from old_table where measure = 'm1'
2. Update m2 having same name.

   UPDATE
       new_table
   SET
       m2 = o.value
   FROM
       new_table n
       JOIN
       old_table o ON o.name = n.name AND o.measure = 'm2'
3. Update m3 having same name.

   UPDATE
       new_table
   SET
       m3 = o.value
   FROM
       new_table n
       JOIN
       old_table o ON o.name = n.name AND o.measure = 'm3'

Not tested. Please test.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `crosstab` from [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tablefunc.html) extension.

Comment: Do you know how to use it. :P